# How separate values with a defined char VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have procedure in VBA to write data to text file (.txt), but I need separeted values this char - "|". Can you help me?

```
Sub Sales_tmr()
Dim myFile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\sales.txt"

Set rng = Selection
Open myFile For Output As #1
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Write #1, cellValue
Else
    Write #1, cellValue,  ' Here I will separeted char "|"
End If
Next j
Next i
Close #1
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with the following object? Maybe that the `Open myFile For Output As #1` has some kind of problem:

```
Dim SpaceVar as String
Dim Writer As Object

SpaceVar = Chr(124) ' Basically your "|"
Set Writer = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
With Writer
    .Type = 2                ' Specifies stream type - save text data.
    .Charset = "utf-8"       ' Specifies charset for the source text data.
    .lineseparator = 10      ' Pushes enter when a line is finished
    .Open
End With

' Here you use the "Writer" Object as many times you want with the strings you want
Writer.WriteText NameVar & SpaceVar & SurnameVar & SpaceVar & AgeVar
' These variables I didn't declare, but you should in case you wanted to use them to store your strings

With Writer
    .SaveToFile FileNameString, 2 ' Saves (and overwrites) data ' be sure to declare the variable, should you use it!
    .Close
End With
Set Writer = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just add it to the value?

```
cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Write #1, cellValue
Else
    cellValue = cellValue & "|"
    Write #1, cellValue,  ' Here I will separeted char "|"
End If
```

***UPDATED***

To make it update each row in one go without quotes and commas. Move your write to after your first loop;

```
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

        cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
        If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
            cellValue = cellValue & "|"
        End If
    Next j

        Write #1, cellValue,
Next i
```

This will output

"Joe|Blogs|72",
"Dave|Mitchell|34",

etc

Comment: That is good idea, but i still have comma and quotation marks near strings. Can I remove comma and quotation marks in the result set in .txt? Result: "John |","White|","43567|","Chicago"

Comment: @user3815737: try to find out where the quotas and commas are written. It's not visible in your code piece. Then remove the corresponding `Write`s. That should do it.

Comment: Sooo we have a problem, because that is whole code... I don't know why this quotas and commas are written...

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw69s8t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx (*"Unlike the Print function, the Write function inserts commas between items and quotation marks around strings as they are written to the file."*)

Comment: @mp24 that is the core of the problem, and the solution.  It deserves to be an Answer!

Answer (score 1):

Please see the documentation to the VB `Write` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw69s8t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

> Unlike the Print function, the Write function inserts commas between items and quotation marks around strings as they are written to the file.

You will have to use a different function to write your lines to a file, e.g. by using `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and `WriteLine`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5399c99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx